# Creating user interface menus in one or separate files on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, filesystems

I'm creating a program with GAS.

I have 2 very similar user interface sub-menus in a sidebar on Google Sheets.

When user is clicking one sub-menu he sees one data, he's clicking the other - a different data.

I have 4 files for one sub-menu: a .gs file, an html file, css file and an html with script file.

**What's same:**

In both my menus there is a select of same people's names and calendars.

**What's different:**

The functionality. The 1st file loads data from calendars to a sheet.
A second file calculates that data and displays on the sidebar below existing elements. Plus there is a button to send emails.

**Do I need to create 4 similar files for a second menu or keep all in these four?**

**I wonder if there might be any conflicts between files.**

Comment: Without knowing all of the details about the code, I'd say that it's possible to reuse the same functions for different sub menus.  You'll just have to identify the unique attributes of each situation and compensate for those differences in code.  I know this isn't a very specific answer, perhaps now you'll understand how I felt when I read your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Thank you. I updated my answer with details.

Comment: I'm assuming that the multiple files imply that your using a templated html approach. So you can have any number of functions in gs file, or a script file so I wouldn't necessarily see any value in multiple files.  But it's probably possible to have one gs file load data from a calendar to a sheet and then return html to a sidebar to be displayed with `.withSuccessHandler()`.  It's up to you to decide.

Comment: I think you should just start coding and see how it goes.  If you don't like what you're doing then do something else until you get what you want.

Comment: Yes I use templated html. Agree. Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you can use "compile time" instructions (setting properties on the `HtmlTemplate` before evaluating) to control how your gs functions are called. Probably you will have the most success with an agnostic "layout-only" HTML file, several choices of `include`able script-only HTML files, and then as many gs files as you like. Parameters in the evaluated template would determine which script HTML get loaded in, and that then determines how the user interacts with your sidebar / UI modal

Comment: @tehhowch that sounds pretty interesting

Comment: Thank you @tehhowch I'll try to implement that)

Comment: can someone help me on that too? I am desparate to locate an error)) @tehhowch  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55432347/get-multiple-corresponding-values-from-different-html-tags-to-use-in-a-function